# Pattern Matching on 'String' to get Escaped Quote

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to pattern match on an escaped quote?

Here's what I (incorrectly) tried:

```
g :: String -> Bool
g ('\\':'"':_) = True
g _            = False
```

But the results don't meet my desired function behavior.

```
ghci> g "\""
False
ghci> g "\\\""
True
```

Comment: Why doesn't it meet the desired behaviour? `g` returns true for exactly the string beginning with the two characters \ and ". So `g "\""` is rightfully false, because it doesn't begin with a \. Just to be clear, the first test string is exactly "  and the second is exactly \" , without the escape characters. Also note that escaping a special character with a backslash does not insert a backslash anywhere into your string - the strings "\n" and "\"", for example, contain no backslashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference between a *string* and a *string literal*. Basically, a string is a list of characters one after the other and a string literal is just some *notation* for the same. The notation has to "escape" certain characters because it would otherwise lead to ambiguous syntax, but it still expresses the string *without* the escaping.

The Haskell expression `"\""` is *notation* for the string containing a single character `"`. We need the backslash because writing `"""` without it would make the contents of the string look just like a closing quote and break our notation. But the string itself still only has a `"`.

When you're matching on a string value, you're matching on the string itself, not its notation. This means that you do not have to worry about escape characters in the string, because those only exist at the level of notation. So to match the string containing just `"` you would use the following pattern:

```
foo ['"'] = ...
```

If you tried to account for a backslash, you would be matching a different string.

Comment: Thanks. and what if I wanted `"\"F"`. How can I pattern match on that case?

Comment: So the literal `"\"F"` corresponds to the *string* `"F`. So you could match on it with `f ['"', 'F']`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: The `[x, y]` pattern matches a list with two elements. To match everything after the `"`, you need to use `:` in your pattern like you did originally: `f ('"':xs) = ...`.