# Haskell breaks my type when I call show/read

Tags: debugging, haskell

I have defined a new type in my haskell code, which takes a list of lists of strings as a record. An example might be
`Board{size=(4,7),pieces=[["OA","AA","AA"],["BBB","BOO"],["OCCC","CCCO","OOCO"]]}`

I've set it up as a derived instance of `Show` and `Read`. If I just input the code above into ghci, then I get out exactly what I put in, which is fine. However, if I call it with show, I get
`"Board {size = (4,7), pieces = [[\"OA\",\"AA\",\"AA\"],[\"BBB\",\"BOO\"],[\"OCCC\",\"CCCO\",\"OOCO\"]]}"`
The speech marks are fine, but I've no idea why the backslashes are there. Are you not allowed to next speech marks or something? In any case, this now totally breaks if I try to call `read` to get it back. I get a long error trying to tell me that none of the strings are data constructors - I don't know why it thinks they are.

Is there any way round this?

Comment: The backslashes are there to escape the double quotes. See, for instance, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28555403/2751851). As for the "long error", what is it exactly? When I try it in GHCi I get a simple `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse`, which goes away if I specify the type of the value being read, as in `read "Board --etc." :: Board`.

Comment: I've realised the problem. I was actually calling `read "Board{size=(4,7),pieces=[["OA","AA","AA"],["BBB","BOO"],["OCCC","CCCO","OOCO"]]}"` manually which has the issue of double quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given

```
> data Board = Board { size :: (Int, Int), pieces :: [[String]] } deriving (Show, Read)
> let b = Board{size=(4,7),pieces=[["OA","AA","AA"],["BBB","BOO"],["OCCC","CCCO","OOCO"]]}
```

The result of `show b` is a `String`

```
> show b
"Board {size = (4,7), pieces = [[\"OA\",\"AA\",\"AA\"],[\"BBB\",\"BOO\"],[\"OCCC\",\"CCCO\",\"OOCO\"]]}"
```

The quotes in any `String` are escaped when `show`-ing a string. If you output the string instead you'll see that it doesn't contain the `\` characters.

```
> putStrLn $ show b
Board {size = (4,7), pieces = [["OA","AA","AA"],["BBB","BOO"],["OCCC","CCCO","OOCO"]]}
```

The string produced by `show` can be read back in again as a board by `read`

```
> (read . show $ b) :: Board
Board {size = (4,7), pieces = [["OA","AA","AA"],["BBB","BOO"],["OCCC","CCCO","OOCO"]]}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Part of it was me making a stupid mistake, and part of it was this.

Answer (score 5):

GHCI already calls `show`. When you type `show something` under GHCI, it’s as if you called `show $ show something`.